# If both A and B columns of a dataset satisfy condition X, then create another column with a value A,B

Tags: dataset, conditional

```
data = Dataset[{<|"userId" -> 5324, 
"PerfFreeResponse" -> 0.8181818181818182`, 
"PerfMultipleChoice" -> 0.5`, "PerfSingleChoice" -> 0.5`, 
"PerfWriteCode" -> 1.`, "MinPerf" -> 0.5`|>, <|"userId" -> 5325, 
"PerfFreeResponse" -> 1.`, "PerfMultipleChoice" -> 1.`, 
"PerfSingleChoice" -> 1.`, "PerfWriteCode" -> 1.`, 
"MinPerf" -> 1.`|>, <|"userId" -> 5326, 
"PerfFreeResponse" -> 0.9090909090909091`, 
"PerfMultipleChoice" -> 0.6666666666666666`, 
"PerfSingleChoice" -> 1.`, "PerfWriteCode" -> 1.`, 
"MinPerf" -> 0.6666666666666666`|>, <|"userId" -> 5330, 
"PerfFreeResponse" -> 0.6363636363636364`, 
"PerfMultipleChoice" -> 0.6666666666666666`, 
"PerfSingleChoice" -> 1.`, "PerfWriteCode" -> 1.`, 
"MinPerf" -> 0.6363636363636364`|>, <|"userId" -> 5331, 
"PerfFreeResponse" -> 0.6363636363636364`, 
"PerfMultipleChoice" -> 1.`, "PerfSingleChoice" -> 1.`, 
"PerfWriteCode" -> 0.`, "MinPerf" -> 0.`|>}]
```

I want to append another column which tells me which type of question (Free response, Multiple Choice, Single Choice, write Code) has the minimum score. I wrote the following code for that:

```
  data[All, Append[#, "MinPerfType" -> 
If[#MinPerf == 1., "Excellent Performance", 
 If[#MinPerf == #PerfFreeResponse, "Free Response", 
  If[#MinPerf == #PerfMultipleChoice, "Multiple Choice", 
   If[#MinPerf == #PerfSingleChoice, "Single Choice", 
    If[#MinPerf == #PerfWriteCode, "Write Code", "Blah"]]]]]] &]
```

But the problem with this code is, if two columns show the MinPerf (except when MinPerf==1.), it gives me the name of only one column and not both of them. Eg., the first row of data shows MinPerf = 0.5, which is true for both Multiple Choice and Single Choice. In that case, I want MinPerfType to show both Multiple Choice and Single Choice and not just either one of them.

Comment: The first advice I would give you, is to look up `Which` to handle the cascading conditions. Also, wouldn't `MinimalBy` be useful for this? `MinimalBy[assoc, Identity]` returns an association containing all keys that have minimal values.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I used MinimalBy and wrote this: `data[All, 
 Append[#, 
   "MinPerfType" -> 
    If[#MinPerf == 1., "Excellent Perf", 
     MinimalBy[{#PerfFreeResponse, #PerfMultipleChoice, \
#PerfSingleChoice, #PerfWriteCode}, #MinPerf]]] &]`. But I need names corresponding to the columns that have the minimum score. MinimalBy satisfies the condition of giving two minimum values but not the corresponding names

Comment: How about `Keys @ MinimalBy[KeyDrop[#, {"userId", "MinPerf"}], Identity]`?

Comment: Perfect. Works. Thank You

Comment: @SjoerdSmit How can I get the elements in string form rather than list form like PerfMultipleChoice, PerfSingleChoice rather than {"PerfMultipleChoice","PerfSingleChoice "}? I tried ToString and then StringDelete, but that doesn't work

Comment: How about something like `StringRiffle[{"PerfMultipleChoice","PerfSingleChoice "}, ", "]`?

Comment: Thank you. It works